# Group by MySQL with special case

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called Master Websites and Defacement Monitor

[Master website Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTa0i.png)

[Defacement Monitor Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqvji.png)

The master_website table contains all the website in the system, and defacement monitor status table filled with status of the each website. We can add status of a website with any date and time statuses are 'safe', 'defaced', 'broken', 'normal', What I want is count of the 'safe','normal', 'broken' with considering only the last entry of each website.
Any help please?
Sorry for my bad english
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post images for sample data instead include sample data in textual format or better to use any online tool, Also include your complete table definitions and expected output

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables together, and then do a LEFT OUTER JOIN against the monitor table looking for a newer row. Using the WHERE clause you can ignore any row where a newer one is found.

Like this:-

```
SELECT dm1.defacement_status, COUNT(dm1.id)
FROM master_website_table m
INNER JOIN defacement_monitor_table dm1
ON m.id = dm1.website_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN defacement_monitor_table dm2
ON m.id = dm2.website_id
AND dm1.defacement_datetime < dm2.defacement_datetime
WHERE dm2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY dm1.defacement_status
```

Note that if any status is not currently used then it will not appear in the results (ie, you will not get a count of 0). It would be better to have a table containing the possible status' (then your monitor table could just use the id from this table instead of the text of the status).